# "How to" for DataSnap Filters Compendium

Tags: delphi, encryption, filter, datasnap

I'm trying to use Daniele Teti's Datasnap Filters Compendiun (the cipher ones) without success. Someone have a 'how to' for cipher filters for Datasnap?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the video here...

[DataSnap Filter Video (Section 5)](http://www.embarcadero-info.com/in_action/radstudio/db.html)

Is there something in particular with the cipher filters you are having trouble with, or filters in general?

Comment: Hi, I cannot change the default password. Also I receive an exception when connect the client side.

Comment: What kind of exception?
Have you included unit CipherFilters.pas in the client?

Comment: Hi Daniele! I have cipherfilters in the client uses clause. I get two problems. First, Server side key is always default_crypt_key almost when changed, except if I change it by code. I see you are using two different parameter names "crypt_key" and "CRYPT KEY". In the client side I always get the same error Filter Blowfish rejected setup parameter default_crypt_key.

Comment: See the last SVN version. Beaviuour has been changed (check the samples)